# how to disbale Namenode web UI?

Tags: security, hdfs, namenode, webui

I want to disable HDFS web UI http://localhost:50070 .
I tried to disable it by below config,however it is still accessible.

```
  <property>
  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>Enable or disable webhdfs. Defaults to false</description>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is WebHDFS, not the WebUI.

You want `dfs.namenode.http-bind-host` set to `127.0.0.1` to make the server bind locally, meaning it is not externally available.

You must restart any Hadoop process after editting its configuration files.

If you use Apache Ambari or Cloudera Manager, it'll request that you do this right away

---

I would advise **not** doing this, though, since you need the UI to be informed about the cluster's overall health, if not using one of the tools I mentioned above.

Comment: for security purpose I want to disable jetty web server on HDFS. not even bind it locally on 127.0.0.1 .

Comment: I don't think Hadoop lets you do this, but you can look at the hdfs-default.xml and search through it yourself. Alternatively, enable SSL and/or SPENGO for solving security issues... Then add Apache Knox ... You need Kerberos for Hadoop to be secure at all, anyway... Not just around web portals

Comment: thanks ,seems it's not possible to disable web UI . I had to enable authentication .